# iptables/ufw: Block specific host access to internet based on time

Tags: networking, server, iptables, ufw

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 as my router/server, which passes traffic over to the internet via interface enp5s0. On my internal interface (enp4s0) I have devices that I wish to restrict from the internet at certain times/days (i.e. parental controls).  So far I've had zero luck in successfully getting this up and running, but best I can tell it should be possible with iptables/ufw.

Can anyone steer me in the right direction with what rules to throw at iptables to restrict a specific host (i.e. 192.168.1.222) from accessing the internet at set times?

I believe my current ruleset is pretty basic (deny all in UFW with some specific ports open to enable day to day use for web etc).

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/iptables-for-restricting-access-by-time-of-day.html

Comment: I'd missed that, but had been on that site.  From that example if I run the below (to test without time restrictions) then restart UFW the device in question still has internet access.  What am I missing?


iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 -d 192.168.1.222 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -j DROP


iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -s 192.168.1.222 -d 0/0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j DROP

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/198398/ubuntu-how-to-add-an-iptables-rule-that-ufw-cant-create

Comment: You're saying put it in before.rules? Or is something from there interfering?

Comment: Your test rules (to test without time restrictions) should be against the FORWARD chain, and prior to any other rule that might cause an ACCEPT. For example: `iptables -A FORWARD -o enp5s0 -s 192.168.1.222 -j DROP` should be good enough.

Comment: I suggest you put your time rules in the OUTPUT chain using  -d .order of rules is important and if the traffic is accepted early you can not filter later. Last I looked ufw did not use a lot in the OUTPUT side. Example here https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.cyberciti.biz/tips/iptables-for-restricting-access-by-time-of-day.html/amp

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something.  Below is my before.rules file as it stands (although I've truncated it after the first section.  Should the rule to drop packets be placed at the top of this file before the rule to route packets to my internet interface?

# NAT table rules
*nat
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# Forward traffic through eth0 or tun0 - depending on VPN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.1.0/24 -o enp5s0 -j MASQUERADE

# don't delete the 'COMMIT' line or these nat table rules won't
# be processed
COMMIT

Comment: There's now progress - the below works, but if I add the time component it seems to ignore the rule.  The rule that works without time settings is :

sudo iptables -I FORWARD -o enp5s0 -s 192.168.1.222 -j DROP

Comment: While the below seems to not work at all. Can anyone suggest what is missing?

sudo iptables -I FORWARD -o enp5s0 -s 192.168.1.222 -m time --timestart 08:00:00 --timestop 18:46:59 --kerneltz -j DROP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help! It all got me to where I was hoping, which was an outcome.

In the end what worked is adding the below to before.rules for each host that I wanted to limit internet hours to:

**# time restrictions for kids devices**

-I FORWARD -o enp5s0 -s 192.168.1.211 -m time --timestart 10:30 --timestop 21:00 -j DROP